# Why is Path.GetFileName(string) returning the full path?

Tags: c#

I have created a PCL (Portable Class Library) to do some logging for my application and have the method:

```
public static void EnterPage([CallerFilePath]string memberName = "")
{
   var file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(memberName);
   Track(file);
}
```

Where `memberName = "d:\\teamFoundation\\MyApp\\MyApp-Reporting\\MyApp.Core\\App.cs"`

and `GetFileName` returns the full path - `d:\\teamFoundation\\MyApp\\MyApp-Reporting\\MyApp.Core\\App.cs` instead of `App.cs`

Is there any reason why this wouldnt be working for a PCL? I am currently running on my `Android` device

Comment: are you running it on a different platform?

Comment: @roryap Portable Class Library

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) state it returns The characters after the last directory character in path, what is your directory character? I imagine it is `/` instead of `\\`?

Comment: I am running on `Android` currently

Comment: You need to find out what your [DirectorySeparatorChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx) is, I'm guessing this is the problem.

Comment: that's your problem - the separator defined is `/` .

Comment: `"d:\\teamFoundation\\MyApp\\MyApp-Reporting\\MyApp.Core\\App.cs"` is my exact path.. This path is given to the method using the `[CallerFilePath]`

Comment: Also these attributes are resolved at compile time, is the file likely to be in the same place once compiled and deployed?

Comment: I'm wondering why you got a down vote.  This question seems legit to me...

Comment: @roryap originally there were not full enough details to what was happening.

Comment: This question has been wildly fluctuating in up and down with votes but this is a legitimate question for a legitimate problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows the `Path` separator is `\` but this is not the same for `Android`

From the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) you can see that the separator is actually `/` and this is the same for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/ManipulatingPaths.html)

The value for `memberName` is passed at compile time and therefore depends on the type of machine you build your solution on. where as the call to `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` is done at runtime.

Therefore to resolve this issue you must replace the separator char in your File Paths:

```
public static void EnterPage([CallerFilePath]string memberName = "")
{
    char seperatorChar = (char)typeof(System.IO.Path).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("DirectorySeparatorChar").GetValue(null);
    var file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(memberName.Replace('\\', seperatorChar));
    Track(file);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used reflection here?

Comment: Good Question.. I actually have no idea, I'd imagine at the time of writing this the property wasn't available, this was very early on in multi app platform development. If there is now a static property to use, please feel free to edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this manually if working cross platform. The value for `memberName` is passed at compile time where the call to `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` is done at runtime. The path separators between Windows and Android are different.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explonation, What is the `Path` seperator for `Android` so that I can test your theory?

Comment: @user1 look at `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` or `System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`

Comment: `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` are not defined for PCL sadly. I may have to use dependency injection and get these values from the device at runtime

Comment: @user1 use `\\` in your calculations if you only build on windows.

Comment: @Sayse I am not creating my path names. C# is giving me the `FileNames` from the `CallStack` hence the `Runtime Attribute`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth it seems that using `/` as a path separator would work from the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). I now have to write my own method to dynamically get and change the Path Separator to get the file name

Comment: @user1 - I thought that might be the case but I wasn't sure, as a simple test to see if this even is the problem you can just do a simple string `.Replace`

Comment: @user1 I'm not sure they are coming from the call stack. The documentation states they are embedded as literals during compile.

Comment: That worked. I will update the answer with more info

Comment: on looking closer I can see `DirectorySeperatorChar` as a private variable on `Path`. There must be some way to access this value and use it through `Reflection` to improve this method